# Fragment views are blank or collapsed first time it opens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm dealing with a weird issue and I'm kind of lost about which direction to take:

I have a fragment which is opened from several places in the app(it shows a user profile). Most of the places it's ok but in one, in particular, it has a strange behavior, the first time it's open, most views are blank, but some like the profile picture and the toolbar title are ok, if I go back and enter it again then all the views are visible as expected.

I have tried several approached to solve this, one, in particular, is to call `activity.recreate()` in the fragment `onCreateView()` which makes the views visible but has some side effects that I want to avoid and also is just a patch and not dealing directly with the problem.

Now, the most strange part to me is that if I open the screen in the layout inspector I see this:

[image]

As you can see the textviews and other elements are set, but just not visible.

One experiment I tried was giving a textview a fixed width and in that case it is visible, could this be some problem with the constraintLayout?

Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

One other thing, could the viewstubs have anything to do here?

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                style="@style/ProfileContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_margin_large_20">

                <include
                        layout="@layout/common_profile_picture"
                        style="@style/ProfileImage"
                        android:id="@+id/userPicture"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/round_avatar_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/round_avatar_size"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
                    android:id="@+id/follow_group"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="user_followers_label_textview,user_followers_number_textview,follow_divider,user_following_label_textview,user_following_number_textview,sectionFollowers,sectionFollowing" />

                <TextView
                        style="@style/ProfileFollowerTextLabel"
                        android:id="@+id/user_followers_label_textview"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/user_following_label_textview"/>
                <TextView
                        style="@style/ProfileFollowerText"
                        android:id="@+id/user_followers_number_textview"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_followers_label_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_followers_label_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/user_followers_label_textview"/>

                <View
                        android:id="@+id/sectionFollowers"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_vertical_divider_height"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_margin_large_28"
                        android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/user_followers_label_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_followers_label_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/user_following_label_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/user_followers_number_textview"/>

                <include layout="@layout/common_divider"
                         android:id="@+id/follow_divider"
                         android:layout_width="1dp"
                         android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_vertical_divider_height"
                         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_margin_large_28"
                         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/user_followers_label_textview"
                         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/user_followers_number_textview"
                         app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/user_followers_label_textview"
                         app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/user_following_label_textview"
                         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"/>

                <TextView
                        style="@style/ProfileFollowingTextLabel"
                        android:id="@+id/user_following_label_textview"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/user_followers_label_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/user_followers_label_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

                <TextView
                        style="@style/ProfileFollowingText"
                        android:id="@+id/user_following_number_textview"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_following_label_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_following_label_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/user_following_label_textview"/>

                <View
                        android:id="@+id/sectionFollowing"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_vertical_divider_height"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_margin_large_28"
                        android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/user_followers_label_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_following_label_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/user_following_label_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/user_following_number_textview"/>

                <ViewStub
                        style="@style/ProfileAction"
                        android:id="@+id/profileaction_viewstub"
                        android:inflatedId="@+id/profileaction_viewstub"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_action_width"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_following_number_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_followers_label_textview"/>

                <TextView
                        style="@style/ProfileName"
                        android:id="@+id/user_fullname_textview"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="@string/placeholder"
                        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_margin_small_4"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userPicture"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/donation_list_label_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/userTitleTextView"
                        style="@style/ProfileTitle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_fullname_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_fullname_textview" />

                <androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiAppCompatTextView
                        style="@style/ProfileDesc"
                        android:id="@+id/user_description_textview"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="@string/placeholderLong"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userTitleTextView"/>

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/userWebSiteTextView"
                        style="@style/ProfileWebSite"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:autoLink="web"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_fullname_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_description_textview" />


                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
                        android:id="@+id/donating_group"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:constraint_referenced_ids="donation_list_label_textview,donating_arrow_imageview,donationList,donationDivider" />

                <include
                        android:id="@+id/donationDivider"
                        layout="@layout/common_divider"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_margin_medium_16"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_margin_medium_16"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_margin_medium_16"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_margin_medium_16"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/donation_list_label_textview"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userWebSiteTextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/donation_list_label_textview"
                    style="@style/ProfileDonatingLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/profile_donating"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_fullname_textview"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/donationDivider" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/donating_arrow_imageview"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_arrow_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_arrow_size"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chevron_accent_right"
                    android:tint="?iconColorSelected"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/donation_list_label_textview"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/donation_list_label_textview"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/donation_list_label_textview"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/donationList"
                    style="@style/TextValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_margin_small_4"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_margin_large_30"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_fullname_textview"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/donation_list_label_textview" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/common_divider"
                     android:id="@+id/postsDivider"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="2dp"
                     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                     app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                     android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_margin_medium_16"
                     android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_margin_medium_16"
                     android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_margin_medium_18"/>

                <include layout="@layout/common_toolbar_back"
                        android:id="@+id/profileToolbar"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/private_profile_textview"
        style="@style/TextValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/profile_private_label_bottom_margin"
        android:text="@string/profile_private"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/postsLoadingProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:theme="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include layout="@layout/loader"
             android:id="@+id/profileLoader"
             android:visibility="gone"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please add all the relevant code (fragment class and layout)

Comment: Simply check your constraints.. it could be the views have wrong widths/heights so they will not fit with there constraints.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I posted the layout code. The class is a bit complicated to post here.

Comment: You use a group within the _ConstraintLayout_ (`follow_group`). Are you sure the group is just not set to `invisible`? That would be a simple explanation.

Comment: until and unless you did not post relevant code here. it's difficult to identify the exact issue.

Comment: share photo when it looks fine.. and also tell either you are replacing or adding fragment?? kindly add that code too

Comment: Enable 'Show layout bounds' from developer options and check the layout at run time when the views aren't visible.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do is check color of the font that you are using. the second is the theme that you are using after that in your fragment xmls root tag put color="white" and clickable is true.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occurred mostly due to the delay and high processing , like your are loading something heavy on your views or overlapping some containers and these are being skipped.

1. **Easy one is just put a background color to this fragment's root container.**
2. **Try to remove overlapping of layouts/views because GPU overrides are increasing and rendering becomes slow.**

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem must be in layout file. As you said when you open layout file the textviews and other elements are set, but just not visible.

That's what troubling the fragment while inflating the views when you open it first time.

**Try:**

1.Check your style.xml and layout file again

2.Debug by replacing the code in layout with simple views